# Всё ли, что произносится вслух, является предложением?

Tags: синтаксис

Предположим, есть стихотворение. Перед стихотворением указывается автор и название. Например, М. Ю. Лермонтов "Парус". Эти конструкции предложениями не являются. Теперь ученик читает это стихотворение в классе вслух. Он говорит: "Михаил Юрьевич Лермонтов. Парус. Белеет парус одинокий..." Если эта конструкция произносится вслух - это уже предложение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне кажется, у вас два вопроса в одном. Сначала про ваш конкретный пример. Вы привели пример "конструкции", которая состоит из нескольких предложений. Такие предложения относятся к [назывному или номинативному](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) типу, а точнее, к [собственно-назывному](https://studopedia.ru/20_8139_sobstvenno-nazivnie-predlozheniya.html) типу.

Вопрос "*Всё ли, что произносится вслух, является предложением?*" несколько философский. Ведь то, что произносится, это *речь*, состоящая из звуков в основе, и, как она воспринимается, влияет на то, как она преобразуется в **предложения**. Если под **предложением** понимать *осмысленное* соединение слов или слово, то мы уходим вглубь к вопросу, *что* является осмысленным и для *кого*.